# 'Original Position' jQuery UI REVERT

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm using jQuery UI Sortable library, you can see the sample here:

[Sortable lists jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists)

I'm using the 'revert' function, which is supposed to revert the position os my element if not dropped in a droppable area; the thing is that for some reason if I'm dragging and go over a droppable area and out, then I release the element and it reverts but to the last droppable area I did over to. I want it to revert to its original position... Hope I explained well myself.

Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/3xW8g/

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Can you post a fiddle recreating your issue?

Comment: Please post your code and/or a demo on jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3xW8g/

Here is the fiddle. If you drag 'Item1' down and go over 'Item99', then release 'Item1' in a blank space outside any of the two lists; it should go back to it's original place. Instead, it'll go back to the last list you 'overed'.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated version of your fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xW8g/7/)

I added a stop handler for your sortables :

```
  stop: function (event, ui) {

        var placePos = ui.placeholder.position();
        var placeWidth = ui.placeholder.outerWidth();
        var total = placePos.left + placeWidth;
        if (ui.position.left > total) $("#sortable1").sortable("cancel");
    }
```

I hope this is what you're looking for.

Edit: here is another version using the beforeStop handler, as I see that there might be problems with the stop. [newFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xW8g/10/)

Comment: Thanks, Bobby! The idea you just gave me is going to help me solve the issue. I actually have more than two sortable lists, so it's going to take a couple more lines to the code, but great! Thank you very much!!

Comment: You can accept it as a correct answer if you consider this as correct. Glad to help.